# jQuery Repeater doesn't work in a partial generated with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, october-partial

In a form consisting of several steps generated in ajax within a single page, I have to use [jquery.repeater](https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater) in an intermediate step.

The form code specific to the repeater is in a dedicated partial

But jquery.repeater does not work, nothing happends when i click on the add or the delete buttons, without even a single javascript error message in the console.

It works if I use this partial directly in a page without the ajax loading.

Note i use the pushing partial updates method in my ajax handler method with

`return [
    '#myDiv' => $this->renderPartial('mypartial')
];`

Welcome for help mates.

here the code i use

and scripts declaration in the bottom of my layout

```
...
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ [
    'assets/javascript/jquery-3.2.1.min.js',
]|theme }}"></script>
{% framework extra %}
{% scripts %}
</body>
</html>
```

my partial

```
<form class="repeater">
    <!--
        The value given to the data-repeater-list attribute will be used as the
        base of rewritten name attributes.  In this example, the first
        data-repeater-item's name attribute would become group-a[0][text-input],
        and the second data-repeater-item would become group-a[1][text-input]
    -->
    <div data-repeater-list="group-a">

      <div data-repeater-item style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" name="text-input" />
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete" />
      </div>

      <div data-repeater-item>
        <input type="text" name="text-input" />
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete" />
      </div>

    </div>

    <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add" />
</form>
```

my page

```
title = "Ajouter"
url = "/tableau-de-bord/espace/ajouter"
layout = "dashboard"
is_hidden = 0

[formulaireCreation]
==
function onStart()
{
    $this->addJs('assets/javascript/node_modules/jquery.repeater/jquery.repeater.js');
    $this->addJs('assets/javascript/my-repeater.js');
}
==
<div id='formulaire-creation-component-wrapper'>
    {% component 'formulaireCreation' %}
</div>
```

my-repeater.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.repeater').repeater({

        // (Optional)
        // "show" is called just after an item is added.  The item is hidden
        // at this point.  If a show callback is not given the item will
        // have $(this).show() called on it.
        show: function () {
            $(this).slideDown();
        },
        // (Optional)
        // "hide" is called when a user clicks on a data-repeater-delete
        // element.  The item is still visible.  "hide" is passed a function
        // as its first argument which will properly remove the item.
        // "hide" allows for a confirmation step, to send a delete request
        // to the server, etc.  If a hide callback is not given the item
        // will be deleted.
        hide: function (deleteElement) {
            if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this element?')) {
                $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
            }
        },
    })
});
```

And finally, for comparison, the code that works in a basic page

```
title = "repeater-test"
url = "/repeater-test"
layout = "dashboard"
is_hidden = 0
==
function onStart()
{
    $this->addJs('assets/javascript/node_modules/jquery.repeater/jquery.repeater.min.js');
    $this->addJs('assets/javascript/my-repeater.js');
}
==
<form class="repeater">

    <div data-repeater-list="group-a">

      <div data-repeater-item style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" name="text-input" />
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete" />
      </div>

      <div data-repeater-item>
        <input type="text" name="text-input" />
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete" />
      </div>

    </div>

    <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a solution, not very elegant but it works

when the partial with the repeater is loaded in ajax, It is as if the page forgot the script declared with `addJS` at the page level, so I declared the script using `<script src="/path/to/myscript.js">` at the end of the partial directly and it works

tried to inject the script with `{% put scripts %}` but doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried using `{% scripts %}` instead of `{% put scripts %}`?

Comment: no but seems strange, according to the october cms documentation. `This tag should appear once only in a given page cycle to prevent duplicated references.` and i already use `{% scripts %}` just before the `</body>` in my layout

Comment: other help from octobercms slack chat: @pat-och: the problem is in your my-repeater.js, on document ready you are looking for .repeater elements
but at first it’s not there. so you need to wrap that function in a new function and call that new function after updating through ajax

Comment: Honestly speaking, I would use something like vuejs for stuff like this. It's going to be laughably simple using components.

Comment: Additionally you could see if jquery-repeater triggers any custom events and then listen for those events before running your custom js instead of relying on document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

Working with JqueryRepeater is like working in hell. Visually it is fantastic but coding something other than the basic is like a kick in the -gg- everytime!

It seems that jQuery don't detect well the new fields of each row, but working with pure JavaScript is possible.

For example, to change the value of a new generated input...

```
Document. getElementsByName ( "your-data-repeater-list[1][field_name]")[0].Value =  "My new value";
```

Where [1] is the new repeater num

I have spent several days (and nights!) working with this component and with some patience it is possible to do whatever you want.

Have fun!